# Keras Image Classification for Different Input Sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use Tensorflow and Keras to train a dataset composed of images with very different sizes in order to classify them. But some of them are horizontal (1400x100) and some of them are vertical (100x1000).
As far as I understand, Keras accepts same size input images.
I'm not sure if it's wise to convert all of them to a classical resolution like 150x150 or 180x180 since they are horizontal and vertical.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few methods have been developed to process images with multiple sizes, including images with unequal horizontal and vertical dimensions. For example, [spatial pyramid pooling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4729) or [scale recurrent neural networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09218). You could also set network [dimensions to be variable](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1920), then use a pooling operation (e.g. global average pooling) to get fixed size dimensions before fully connected or other layers than need a fixed size.

The simplest approach is cropping or padding images (e.g. with zeros) so that they are all the same size.